# Como criar um "Event Scheduler" no MySQL cujo valor do intervalo vem do próprio banco de dados?

Tags: mysql, scheduler

Eu estou usando o seguinte código para gerar uma **Tarefa** ou **Event Schedule** no MySQL a cada 10 segundos:

```
delimiter |
CREATE EVENT gera_financeiro_contrato
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 SECOND STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
    COMMENT 'Gera financeiro no contrato'
    DO
    BEGIN
        insert into grupos (nome, ) values (concat('teste -', UNIX_TIMESTAMP() ) );
    END|

delimiter ;
```

O código acima esta correto e funcionando, porém eu preciso deixar o usuário alterar a frequência da execução da **Tarefa**, por exemplo se a tarefa foi criada para ser executada a cada 10 segundos `ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 SECOND`, como eu faço para a tarefa ler uma determinada tabela e obter o valor de intervalo para execução?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa fazer uma subquery para saber o novo valor do intervalo, o código ficaria assim:

```
delimiter |
CREATE EVENT gera_financeiro_contrato
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY (select valor from tabela where campo = especificacao) SECOND STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
    COMMENT 'Gera financeiro no contrato'
    DO
    BEGIN
        insert into grupos (nome, ) values (concat('teste -', UNIX_TIMESTAMP() ) );
    END|

delimiter ;
```

Comment: A sua resposta me ajudou muito obrigado, porém ainda não resolvi todo o meu problema e eu só vi isso depois de fazer a tarefa funcionar, valeu!